# Return key in IOS/android + phonegap/cordova framework

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova

I am creating an app in IOS/android with phonegap/cordova framework. I have a set of input types like input boxes, picklists, etc. How can I set the return key to work such that it focuses on the next input box when pressed. I have tried to use javascript in phonegap like:
`document.getElementByid('nextElement').focus();`

on return/enter; But it does'nt seem to be working ie. focus is lost from the current element but the soft keyboard is vanishing and focus is not coming to the next element. Any idea of where am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

After some googling, it turns out this is not possible on Mobile Safari (although desktop WebKit works).

You can set focus on next element, but soft keyboard won't appear at all.

Here's the PoC of this: http://www.hakoniemi.net/labs/focusOnNext/

Comment: No I have seen this in native IOS apps where it seems to be possible like in mail app in iphone/ipod.

Comment: True, maybe you can set custom handling for HTML input elements for WebView (you were talking about HTML hybrid app, right?) via Objective-C.